# How to set the background color of a column in gridview of WPF

Tags: wpf, gridview, datatable

My gridview is dynamically generated from a Datatable read from SQL, now I want to set a particular column, say, "salary" to have a red background color. I've searched SO for many solutions but still have no clues.

```
CmdString = @"  select id, firstname, lastname, title, level, salary from emplpyees";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt = new DataTable("employee");
            sda.Fill(dt);
            datagridall.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Comment: Have you tried using a DataGridTemplateColumn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a converter class

```
public class ErrorConverters : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      SolidColorBrush myBrush = default(SolidColorBrush);

      if ((bool)value == true)
      {
        myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
      }
      else
      {
        myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
      }

      return myBrush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      //Throw New NotImplementedException()
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Then using a row template bind the back color to whatever item in your database would be passed to the converter.

Answer (score 2):

Try Below Code:

`gvUserInfo.Columns[0].ItemStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;`

Put the same code in BindGrid Function after `gvUserInfo.DataBind();`

Enjoy..

Comment: there is no property called ItemStyle for gvUserInfo.Columns[0]

Comment: It should be there this is the property of Grid, What kind of error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Code:

```
protected void gvBandA_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
     //   e.Row.Cells[1].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        gvBandA.Columns[1].ItemStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        gvBandA.Columns[1].ItemStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Fuchsia;
    }
```