# How can I change the Background color of a GridViewColumn dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

In the main, I've the following:

```
   List<Person> items = new List<Person>();
   Person p = new Person() { NameP = "Samantha", Gen = true, Feb = true, Mar = false, Apr = false, Mag = false, Lug = false, Ago = false, Set = false, Ott = false, Nov = false, Dic = false };
   items.Add(new Person() { NameP = "Jack", Gen = true, Feb = true, Mar = true, Apr = true, Mag = false, Lug = false, Ago = false, Set = false, Ott = false, Nov = false, Dic = false });
   listView.ItemsSource = items;
```

Where a Person is a class composed by a string NameP and 12 boolean, one for month.

I managed to see them in a GridView internal of a ListView. The result is the following:
[image]

Now, I have to change the Background in yellow of all the item which are "true", and I've no idea. This is the xaml code:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Height="144">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width ="150" Header="NAMEP" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NameP}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width ="50" Header="GEN" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Gen}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width ="50" Header="FEB" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Feb}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width ="50" Header="MAR" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mar}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width ="50" Header="APR" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Apr}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width ="50" Header="MAG" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mag}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width ="50" Header="GIU" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Giu}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width ="50" Header="LUG" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Lug}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width ="50" Header="AGO" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Ago}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width ="50" Header="SET" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Set}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width ="50" Header="OTT" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Ott}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width ="50" Header="NOV" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Nov}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width ="50" Header="DIC" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Dic}"/> 
                </GridView> 
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Thanks for your suggestion.

Possible duplicated of.... : No,  I need to change the color dinamically, not in a static way as requested in the question that signaled me as duplicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting Column Background in WPF ListView/Gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379902/setting-column-background-in-wpf-listview-gridview)

Comment: @C-PoundGuru No, it isn't a duplicate. I need to change the color dinamically, not in a static way as requested in your question

Comment: How about [How to set the background color of a column in gridview of WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863607/how-to-set-the-background-color-of-a-column-in-gridview-of-wpf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write style for list view

Write a Style which highlights ListViewItems

```
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Text}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Text}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" Width="50"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemID}" Width="auto" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ShipCity" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemSerialNumber}" Width="auto"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

[Highlighting-Items-in-a-WPF-ListView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18585/Highlighting-Items-in-a-WPF-ListView)

Comment: It doesn't work... i read your link but it crash! I wrote "Binding Gen" and Value="Red" and 
      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemContStyle}" in the ListView...

Comment: @JoeMatt i updated the code , it use an hack  check string you can write converter if you want. it have a small issue it set color to all column  :(

Answer (score 3):

You can use converter to convert your Boolean value to right background

```
<GridViewColumn Width ="50" Header="GEN" >
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Gen}" Background="{Binding Gen, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}" />
         </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Converter looks like this

```
 class BackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is bool && (bool)value)
        {
            return Application.Current.FindResource("ActiveBrush");
        }

        return Application.Current.FindResource("DefaultBrush");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Brushes in App.Resources

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DefaultBrush" Color="Red" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ActiveBrush" Color="Yellow" />
```